# Is there a way to add XYZ Tile Layer to QGIS from an AWS bucket?

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service, amazon-web-services

I am trying to add Map tiles from Pix4D to QGIS.  Has anyone successfully accomplished this? I have loaded XYZ tiles to an Amazon AWS bucket and things seem to work fine with leaflet [(LINK)](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html).  The files are in Zoom, with a string like this:

```
'https://mycooltiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2023_0322/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

Inside the **HTML** code =>

```
var tms_example = L.tileLayer('https://mycooltiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2023_0322/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true}).addTo(map);
```

And a directory structure like this:
[image: AWS File structure]

I have tried QGIS Create NEW WMS Connection [image] as well as XYZ tiles.  I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Please  [Edit] the Question to choose one product stack to be the focus of your Question. Any time you put "ArcGIS Pro or QGIS" in a title you will quickly compile close votes.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to connect through the "XYZ Tiles" tile manager...

Comment: I have tried the Tile Manager nearly every way possible.  Leaflet has no issue with adding tiled images but QGIS is failing.